# Canvas not working as intended

Tags: html, canvas

I was trying a script to draw graph paper like grids on the canvas from dive into html5. The result is supposed to draw a mesh with squares of side 10px but i'm getting the size as approximately 20px, and not exact squares.
Here is the code,`

```
   <html>
      <head>     
           <style>
    body{
        margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    }

    canvas{
        width: 500px;
        height: 375px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function activate(){
            var canvas =document.getElementById("exp");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            for (var x=0.5;x<500;x+=10){
                context.moveTo(x,0);
                context.lineTo(x,375);
                console.log(x);
            }

            for (var y=0.5;y<375;y+=10){
                context.moveTo(0,y);
                context.lineTo(500,y);
            }

            context.strokeStyle="#000";
            context.stroke();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="exp"><script type="text/javascript">activate();</script></canvas>
</body
     </html>
```

And this is the output:
 [image: canvas rendered] 
while the actual output should be: 
 [image: actual canvas] 
Note: i'm not worried about the color difference. what i don't understand is why the space between 2 lines is ~20px(as checked by a measurement tool on firefox) instead of 10px.

 Also, on printing the values of x, it gives the right value(i.e. incremented by 10 each time).

Comment: You are missing a `>` in `</body>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not set the canvas' size with css
you should set in the DOM's attribute.

```
<canvas width="100" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: ya that worked, but i don't understand how the css changed the line width? Also, as you said the css didn't get applied to the canvas, but the canvas still acquired the size of 502x377px(exactly). Why?

Comment: The css just change style's width and height but not the canvas's width and height. canvas just like an image, you set image's style width and height would not change the actual size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can calculate for you. Only set the parameters:

html:

```
<canvas id="exp"></canvas>
```

js:

```
function activate(id, xcount, ycount, width, color) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(id);
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = xcount * width + 1;
    canvas.height = ycount * width + 1;

    for (var x = 0.5; x < canvas.width; x += width) {
        context.moveTo(x, 0);
        context.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
    }

    for (var y = 0.5; y < canvas.height; y += width) {
        context.moveTo(0, y);
        context.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
    }

    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.stroke();
}
activate("exp", 37, 50, 10, "#ccc");
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gyn4c/5/).